# Run a macro in a specified worksheet from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Here's my problem: I have two workbooks, one is mine, say Projet.xlsm, and the other is not, say Query.xlsm. Query.xlsm is shared between me and a lots of people in my company so I can't modify it.

My project.xlsm aims to plot some datas extracted with Query.xlsm. My job is to make it an automated process.

How Query.xlsm work: on the first sheet there is some options to select; then we have just to click a button on the first sheet. Finally all the datas are extracted and appears in second sheet.

I've built a macro in project.xlsm wich open Query.xlsm and select the options I want.
Now I'm tryi,g to "click the button" (sheet1 in Query.xlsm) from my macro in my project.xlsm. I've tried things like this: [running excel macro from another workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806065/running-excel-macro-from-another-workbook)
But I think I have to mention the name of my sheet somewhere.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the workbook open (which it sounds like you do), this worked for me even on a Private CommandButton Sub.

```
Workbooks("Query.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1 = True
Workbooks("Query.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1 = vbClick
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a public procedure in **Query.xlsm** Workbook in first sheet. 
cmdClick refers to the name of activex command button. Below is sample code.

```
Public Sub cmdClick()
    CommandButton1_Click
End Sub
```

You can call this procedure from  **project.xlsm** using below syntax.

```
Workbooks("testing.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").cmdClick
```

Comment: As Query.xlsm is used by a lots of people I can't modify it easily.