# Make macro run in specific workbook

Tags: vba, excel, macros

This seems like such a simple request, but I can't seem to find any answers online. 
I have two open workbooks (lets say **A** and **B**). All I want to do is run a macro that I have created in **Workbook B** and run it (by click a shape that I've assigned a macro to) through **Workbook A**, but the macro running in **Workbook B**

The macro I created for **Workbook B** is...

```
Sub HistoricalDataShift()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets
        ws.Activate'
        Rows("18:1000").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("A19").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Rows("15:15").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("A18").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Then I created a second macro in **Workbook B** that has...

```
Sub ApplicationRun()
    Application.Run ("WorkbookB.xlsm!HistoricalDataShift")
End Sub
```

But each time I try the macro keeps running in **Workbook A**.

If I could get a helping hand that would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running excel macro from another workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806065/running-excel-macro-from-another-workbook)

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate question of the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806065/running-excel-macro-from-another-workbook Note, that the macro you wrote is not designed to be used from another workbook because it lacks the explicit reference of the workbook to be used when copying and pasting.

Comment: @Ralph This isn't a duplicate of those because `Application.Run` works just fine for the OP. The OP's problem is that the code in Workbook B is written without explicitly stating which workbook it is supposed to operate on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is rewrite HistoricalDataShift to operate on itself. It should work just fine then.

```
Sub HistoricalDataShift()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ws.Activate '
        ws.Rows("18:1000").Select
        Selection.Copy
        ws.Range("A19").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ws.Rows("15:15").Select
        Selection.Copy
        ws.Range("A18").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Also to make your code work better, you can do this:

```
Sub HistoricalDataShift()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    wb.Activate
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Call ws.Rows("18:1000").Copy(ws.Range("A19"))
        Call ws.Rows("15:15").Copy(ws.Range("A18"))
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @D_Bester, I know this is a second question but how would I change your formula above so that row 15 is pasted as values only in A18 (I've been playing with `PasteSpecial` but just can't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring your workbook object?

```
Dim wkbkA as workbook
set wkbkA = 'directory here
```

then run your code in a `With... End With`

```
With wkbkA
    .range('etc.........

End With
```

Comment: Declaring the workbook object is necessary because HistoricalDataShift needs to refer to itself. But you haven't explained that connection.

Comment: Good point, I had your answer in mind and 3 minutes to type a cogent response

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Worksheets("<worksheetname>")`

e.g. `Worksheets("A").Activate`

or `cv = Worksheets(Worksheet).Cells(DataSeriesEnd, rc_index)`

*where Worksheet holds the sheet name.*

etc.

This snippet will go through the entire collection of worksheets, where w is the current worksheet name :-

```
For Each w In Worksheets
    .......
Next w
```

Comment: Activating the workbook then activating the worksheet would work but you haven't really explained how to do that.

Comment: The question included use of ws.activate and as such I felt there was little need to re-invent the proverbial wheel. Rather to provide examples based upon the given code. Hence the example using activate and also an example using cell references.

Answer (score 1):

In this short example, we assume that *WorkbookB.xlsm* is initially the only open workbook and hosts this macro:

```
Sub HistoricalDataShift()
    Dim wkbB As Workbook
    Dim wkbA As Workbook

    Set wkbB = ThisWorkbook
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="WorkbookA"
    Set wkbA = ActiveWorkbook
    wkbA.Sheets(1).Range("B9").Value = "whatever"
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't really work with the OP's framework because workbook A is calling  workbook B. So you don't want workbook B opening workbook A.