# In VBA, can a workbook object reference a method written in one of its worksheets?

Tags: vba, excel

Edited to provide more information.

**Base Question:**

Is it possible for a workbook to have access to a method written in one of its worksheets in VBA?

**Real World Reason:**

I need to have a method run on workbook launch (Workbook_Open() event) however, that method has a few requirements which makes modules not viable:

1. Needs to maintain state
2. Needs to store data
3. Needs to be referenced from both the workbook, and the worksheets in said workbook

**Psuedocode example:**

**myWorkbook**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call myWorkbook.Sheet("worksheet1").helloWorld
End Sub
```

**worksheet1**

```
Public Sub printHelloWorld()

    'Store "Hello World" so we can use later, this method needs to maintain state
    Dim helloWorld As String
    Set helloWorld = "Hello World"

    MsgBox(helloWorld)
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try it? What did you get? Hint: `Workbook` doesn't have a `Sheet` member. Try posting code from your IDE instead of typing it out in the question box. Yes/No questions are particularly bad on this site. See [ask].

Comment: You can make it a little simpler with **Application.Run ("'L:\database\lcmsmacro\macro1.xlsm'!macro_name","param1","param2")**, courtesy of @Fink via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806065/running-excel-macro-from-another-workbook

Comment: I don't consider this JUST a yes/no question. If the answer is yes, then there would a "How" aspect to it. The actual code provided was more or so pseudo code, my bad on the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. Both of the below work fine.

```
Sub TestWithExplicitWorksheet()
    wsTest.TestMessage
End Sub

Sub TestWithWorksheetsCollection()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").TestMessage
End Sub
```

wsTest Code:

```
Sub TestMessage()
    Debug.Print "Success"
End Sub
```

A Worksheet is more or less a Predeclared Class Module. So if you can do it with a Class, you should be able to do it with a Worksheet. Since the Worksheets collection of the Workbook object returns (if found) a Worksheet object, you can call the method on this returned object (if it's the correct object and contains the sub being called).

Answer (score 0):

I would put the code below in a module

```
Public Sub printHelloWorld()
    MsgBox("Hello World")
End Sub
```

and the code in myWorkBook will look like

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    printHelloWorld
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the sheet [`CodeName`](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm) (you can also change it in the sheet object properties):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet1.printHelloWorld()        ' full name is VBAProject.Sheet1.printHelloWorld()
End Sub
```